# Determine the focal length of a biconvex lens

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, lenses

I'm struggling to find any information on this topic online. I've been asked to find the focal length of a biconvex lens with these specifications:

Refractive index: 1.5
Total Height: 7.5cm
Radius of Curvature: 6cm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radius of curvature and focal length](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168749/)

Comment: Have you looked up the Lens-Maker's Formula?